# Bones triangle segments gone

Tags: rigging, bones

[image]

I'm new to Blender, and a few times I've loaded in other peoples models and
noticed the "triangle" segments like in the right picture are completely gone, so it's kind of hard to select the bones themselves to add a simple IK rig.

Are they hidden, gone, or a different type of bone all together?

If the last is the case, how do I change them?

Answer (score 1):

What you call triangle segments are octahedral bones, they are the way bones display by default. You can change the appearance of bones, for example you can switch to rectangular bones: Select the armature, go to the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *Viewport Display* > *Display as*.

But you can also replace a bone by a custom object, meaning whatever shape you want: Switch your armature to *Pose* mode, select one of your bones, go to the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Viewport Display* > *Custom Object*, click on the X if you want to come back to the default octahedral shape.

That said I'm not sure how your armature works...

[image]